# OpenAM as OAuth 2.0 provider and java client example

Tags: oauth-2.0, openam

I am trying out OpenAM as an OAuth 2.0 provider and would like to find an example of setting up OpenAM for this purpose and a client code in Java.
Can anyone help please?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I would stard by reading the offical doc:
[AM 7 doc](https://backstage.forgerock.com/docs/am/7/oauth2-guide/oauth2-configure-authz.html)

To test if your oauth2 provider works or not, you dont need a client app, just a shell to test few curl commands (i.e. client credentials flow: get token, introspect token, revoke token)

As for your real tests you can find plenty of ready to use apps on github, almost all vendors have thier own repo with test apps in java, spring, python ...

[Okta example wich will work perfectly on openam](https://github.com/oktadev/okta-java-spring-sso-example)

[Keycloak example apps](https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak-quickstarts)